# "Forward this email" creates contacts with e-mail and no first/last name

Tags: civimail

If you click the "Forward this Email" link on a CiviMail mailing, you get a screen that allows you to create records with no first/last name (see attached screenshot).  Moreover, there's nothing to indicate how they got into CiviCRM.  What would be the best fix for this?

- Force someone to enter a first/last name (similar to "Tell-a-Friend" on event reg);
- Create an activity (or even relationship) linking this user to the user who submitted their mail - again, similar to Tell-A-Friend;
- something else entirely?

I understand the need to make it easy to forward an e-mail without giving additional information - but it's also not OK to have records with no way to tell how they got into the system.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think that page has not changed since it was first implemented. I'd probably vote for the following changes:

a. Add optional form fields first name and last name

b. Create an activity to make it similar to tell-a-friend, which is kinda the same concept

Answer (score 2):

I agree this is less than ideal. Probably the minimum solution would be to fill the "source" field for the newly created contacts with e.g. "Forward email from Bob Smith".